# How to store and reference input for a travel expense program in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, hashmap

I am a beginner in Ruby and I am writing a travel expense tracker that will calculate the amount spent on each trip and the percentage of total travel expense for each trip. (So far I can only calculate the total spent on all trips combined)                                                                        First I want to also be able to calculate the total expense for each trip. How do I reference the user input to do this?
                                                                                In addition, I am also wondering how I can reference the trip locations that were entered by the user, Example: "your trip to Spain made up 50% of the cost of all trips."

This is what I have so far:

```
# asks the user how many trips they've taken and prompts them that number of times
puts "How many trips did you take?"
trip_count = gets.chomp.to_i

# prompts the user the trip locations and stores them in a hash
trip_data = trip_count.times.map do |x| 
puts "Where did you go for your trip ##{x+1}?" 
trip_location = gets.chomp

puts "How much did you spend on lodging?"
lodging_cost = gets.chomp.to_i

puts "How much did you spend on round-trip transportation?"
transit_cost = gets.chomp.to_i

puts "How many bags did you check?"
bags_checked = gets.chomp.to_i

{
location: trip_location,
lodging: lodging_cost,
transit: transit_cost,
bags: bags_checked *50
}
end

#total spent on all trips
total_spent = trip_data.reduce(0) do |sum, trip| sum + trip[:lodging] + trip[:transit] + trip[:bags] 
end
```

Comment: So what isn’t working?

Comment: I want to know how I can calculate how much was spent on a single trip and also how I can reference the entered trip location in text, for example: "your trip to Spain costed $1500"

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in a table in a database. I suggest looking into a sqlite3 db that will be easy to manage. Here is the sqlite3 repository in github that contains some good information on how to use it if you look in the Readme https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby.

Step 0: Connect to database

```
require "sqlite3"

db = SQLite3::Database.new "myTrips.db"
db.results_as_hash = true
```

Step 1: Basically, to make it easy you can create a table that contains a column for each of these questions plus one for the total.

```
 rows = db.execute <<-SQL
   create table Trips (
     trip_pk integer primary key autoincrement,
     location varchar(50),
     lodging_cost float,
     transit_cost float,
     bags_cost float,
     total_cost float
   );
 SQL
```

Step 2: Each time you go through your program and answer the questions you could insert a new record into the table. So, each row would represent one trip. The responses that you enter would be added to the SQL statement below in the values section. You can enter these dynamically by using the hash you already formed in your example above which looks like this:

```
responses = {
  location: trip_location,
  lodging: lodging_cost,
  transit: transit_cost,
  bags: bags_checked *50
}

def add_new_trip
  total = responses[:lodging] + responses[:transit] + responses[:bags]

  db.execute("insert into Trips(location, lodging_cost, transit_cost, 
  number_of_bags, total_cost) values(responses[:location], responses[:lodging], responses[:transit], responses[:bags], total)")
```

Step 3: Then once you have data populated in the database you can query for the information you want. So if you wanted to get the cost of your trip to Spain you would execute this sql statement:

```
select total_price from Trips where location = 'Spain'
```

You can use this to help with your percentage calculation.

Keep in mind that some of this is pseudo code and might not work exactly out of the bag but if you take a look at the link I posted you should be able to find what you are looking for to fill in the blanks.